# Google Cloud Compute Instance, IPv6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I currently have a google cloud compute instance set up to be the back-end for a multiplayer game. Certain publishers and app stores that I'm trying to publish the game on require that the server can be reached via a client using an IPv6 address, which makes perfect sense. So the question is, how do I go about making it that the compute instance can be connected to via IPv6?

It's worth noting that the connection between the client and server is done via UDP, so using load balancing doesn't appear to work (since load balancers in google cloud can only be done over TCP, from what I can tell).

Has anyone else had this issue, and if so how did you solve it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: At this time, Google does not support UDP load balancing for IPv6. Compute Engine does not yet support IPv6 for public IP addresses. IPv6 is not as popular as I would expect in 2019. I am still waiting for my home ISP to support IPv6.

Answer (score 4):

IPv6 Termination for HTTP(S), SSL Proxy, and TCP Proxy Load Balancing is currently in Beta.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ipv6

Configuring IPv6 termination for your load balancers lets your backend instances appear as IPv6 applications to your IPv6 clients.

Note: The documentation says this feature is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and may be subject to backward-incompatible changes.

The definition of Beta from their documentation: Beta is the point at which we are ready to open a release for any customer to use. There are no SLA or technical support obligations in a Beta release, and charges may be waived in some cases. Products will be complete from a feature perspective, but may have some open outstanding issues. Beta releases are suitable for limited production use cases.

https://cloud.google.com/terms/launch-stages

Comment: Yeah, I had already come across this information. In my original question though I am referring to the use of UDP, you'll notice that they don't suggest support for UDP in their current documentation so I was wondering if there may be a away to work around that, rather than have to look for another service provider...

Comment: Sorry about that.  If I understand correctly only their network load balancing supports both TCP and UDP.  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/  The network load balancing does not support IPv6, though.

Comment: How ironic is this? External IPv4 addresses can be regional, but IPv6 are global only.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 Termination for HTTP(S), SSL Proxy, and TCP Proxy Load Balancing became GA on September 20, 2017.

Source: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/announcing-ipv6-global-load-balancing-ga.html.

See the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/ipv6

Keep in mind that inside the GCP network, all is still on IPv4, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904387

Comment: Still no mention of UDP in documentation, though.

Answer (score 1):

May 2022 update.

Per https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#limitations

Internal and external IPv6 subnets are available in all but asia-southeast2 and asia-northeast3 regions.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud now supports external ipv6 on VM instances. Each instance can get a /96 external ip range and it can be used to access internet (without NAT) or be used for VM to VM traffic.

At this moment (July 2021) it's only supported limited regions:

- asia-east1
- asia-south1
- europe-west2
- us-west2

See more detailed in

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ipv6-addresses

If your instance happened to be one of the 4 regions above then you should be able to use the VM instance IPv6 feature.